# IllegalArgumentException when using parsing CSV using apache commons csv - CSVFormat

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

I am parsing a CSV file using Apache commons CSV
using the following code:

```
CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL);
```

On some of the CSV files I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Mapping for Phone number not found, 
expected one of [Address, City, State, Zip, Phone Number, Product, Comments/Description, Final Status, Date Closed]
```

I checked the file, it contains a"Phone Number" column, column exist and all the values present.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Export the file from Excel to TEXT (CSV or whatever), then look at the raw data (using Notepad++ perhaps) to see if anything is weird.  You could have  stray CR/LF characters or stray quotes (only one quote without the finishing quote) or lots of errors in actual CSV format.  Excel is renowned for this.  If you try to IMPORT that TEXT file into MySQL or SQL Server - it will probably give you a better error with the line number

Comment: There is a difference in case, "number" vs "Number" in your question, maybe this is causing problems?

Comment: this is correct centic, there is a feature on this              https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CSV-159     please have this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your exception message the **n** of **Phone number** is small but the field contains it in **Phone Number** form. The error will not arrive when it will found a column named in the above message.